# how to update object data of the state in react

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I have a form, firstly, i will show the values from the editformData state

```
const [editformData, setEditformData] = useState([{name: 'John', age: '28'}]);
```

Below is the form

```
<Form.Control
  type="text"
  name="first_name"
  required
  value={editformData[0].name}
  onChange={handleInput}
/>
```

On handle input i want to update the input field and also overwrite the same editformData

```
const handleInput = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const name = e.target.name;

  setEditformData(() => ({
    [name]: value,
  }));
  
};
```

But when the setEditformData is updated, the previous values are gone and all the form data is reset.
So i tried to retain previous state, but i'm unable to update the existing object data.

```
const handleInput = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const name = e.target.name;

  setEditformData((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [name]: value,
  }));
  
};
//output is [{name: 'John', age: '28'}, {name: Doe}] //typed value is appended
```

The existing object data is not replaced. Expected something like below but it throws error

```
const handleInput = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const name = e.target.name;

  setEditformData((prev) => ([
    prev[0][name] : value,
  ]));
  
};

Expected output: [{name: 'Doe', age: '28'}]
```

Comment: You have initialized `editformData` as an array then inside `handleInput` you are setting it as an object. I am not sure why would you do that. Do you want arrays all along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your state is an array, I'm assuming you've got multiple forms of the same shape. If it's just a single form, this `useState([{name: 'John', age: '28'}]);` should not be an array.

---

The handler:

```js
const handleInput = (e, formIndex) => {
    const {value, name} = e.target;
    setEditformData(prev => {
        const arrCopy = [...prev];
        arrCopy[formIndex] = {...arrCopy[formIndex], [name]: value};
        return arrCopy;
    });
};
```

---

You also need to pass the `formIndex`, I'm assuming you're iterating over something:

```
{someArray.map((val, i) => <input onChange={e => handleInput(e, i)}></input>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

if `editformData` is initialized like this `const [editformData, setEditformData] = useState({name: 'John', age: '28'})` then you should be able to achieve desired result by using higher order functions. Something like below -

```
//You will have to do the same changes to your age input field. onChange is a higher-order function.
<Form.Control
  type="text"
  name="name"
  required
  value={editformData.name}
  onChange={handleInput('name')}
/>

const handleInput = param => (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  setEditformData({...editformData, [param]: value});
};
```